# Managing latest versions of rows with group by queries and how to best arrange the primary key

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have the following table

```
| Path          | Version | FirstName | LastName |
| People/Frank  | 1       | Frank     | Smith    |
| People/Frank  | 2       | Frank     | Jones    |
| People/Jack   | 1       | Jack      | Johnson  |
```

I'd like my query to return the `Path` and `Max Version` for all the rows that match a given criteria.

Currently I'm doing this;

```
select Path, MAX(Version) as Version from Table where FirstName = 'Frank' group by Path;
```

This is a really performance critical part of the code and I'm wondering if there's something specific I can do to sql server that would make this quicker or if there's something I'm missing.

Additionally I'd like to make sure I have my constraints defined correctly.  I'm expecting the queries to contain any or all of the columns that aren't path and version, so you could in the above case query for either FirstName, LastName or both.  My create table sql looks like this:

```
create table Index_PersonByFirstName(
   FirstName NVarChar(100) not null, 
   LastName NVarChar(100) not null, 
   Path NVarChar(100) not null, 
   Version Int not null, 

   constraint pk_Index_PersonByFirstName primary key(
      FirstName, 
      LastName, 
      Path, 
      Version), 

    constraint uc_Index_PersonByFirstName_Path_Version unique (
      Path, 
      Version), 

    constraint fk_People_Path_Version foreign key (
      Path, 
      Version) REFERENCES People(Path, Version))
```

Would it make sense to remove the `Path` from the primary key as that's never directly queried?

Another option I've considered is having a column that indicates if the row is the 'latest' version for a given path and updating the old rows when a new one is written, but that feels icky.

Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  If I haven't been detailed enough please let me know and I'll add any other information that is required.

Answer (score 1):

The query is fine. That's the textbook right way to do it.

The primary key should be the minimum set of fields that uniquely identify a record. Is your example above your actual database or just a simplified or hypothetical example? Because it's pretty unlikely that first name plus last name can be guaranteed to be unique. Are you sure you will never have two "Jim Smith"s? I don't know how the "path" is defined. Maybe that's under your control so that you could guarantee that it's unique.

Don't add fields to a primary key just because this is what you want to sort or select on. Use alternate indexes for that.

**Update based on wild guesses about your examples**

I don't know what your data means or what you're trying to do. But I'd guess that first and last name are really dependent on the path. That is, you won't have:

```
path        vers first name  last name
----        ---- ----------  ---------
/foo/fredm  1    Fred        Miller
/foo/fredm  2    Fred        Miller
/foo/fredm  1    Sally       Jones
```

If that's true, then you really should have a table with Path, First Name, Last Name, maybe other data, and key of Path. Then a separate table with Path and Version and whatever data is dependent on the version.

Otherwise, there is the potential for your database to contain contradictory data. If a Path is supposed to map to only one name, what happens if, by some sort of coding or data entry mistake, you get one record with path "fredm" and name "Fred Miller" and another with path "fredm" and name "Frank Mendel"? Queries expecting them to always be the same could end up picking one at random and giving inconsistent results, or you could get two records where you thought you should have one, etc. One of the prime rules of good database design is: Don't store redundant data.

Comment: It's a theoretical example, but the reason why I include Path in the key is the for the reason you state, there could be two Jim Smiths.  There could also be two Jim Smiths with the same path, but not the same version.

Comment: So if the minimum set of data to uniquely identify a record is first name plus last name plus path plus version, then that would be a candidate primary key. Frankly, a primary key that takes four fields is pretty cumbersome. I'd be looking at inventing a synthetic key, i.e. a sequence number, as your primary key to be used when linking between record types, and let that bundle of fields be an index.

Comment: Also, if there's any data that depends on only a portion of this key, like there is data that is the same for every name and path regardless of the version, then that should be broken out into a separate table.

Comment: After some more thinking I'm contemplating making path a separate table, so the column on the index table can be an int which should be quicker.  The PK will be a path+version (unclustered) and then a clustered index on firstname, lastname.  How does that sound?